# How to use Repeater field of advance custom field

Tags: plugins

I have crated one Repeater field with four sub field,
how to write code in the place of my html

for exp ,this a HTML code

```
<ul>
                    <li class="first">
                        <a href="service_detail.html">
                            <div class="img-blk"><img src="images/fencing1.png" class="nor" alt="" /><img src="images/fencing1h.png" class="hov" alt="" /></div>
                            <h3>Fencing</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="service_detail.html">
                            <div class="img-blk"><img src="images/slashing1.png" class="nor" alt="" /><img src="images/slashing1h.png" class="hov" alt="" /></div>
                            <h3>Slashing</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="service_detail.html">
                            <div class="img-blk"><img src="images/earth1.png" class="nor" alt="" /><img src="images/earth1h.png" class="hov" alt="" /></div>
                            <h3>Earthwork</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="service_detail.html">
                            <div class="img-blk"><img src="images/exca1.png" class="nor" alt="" /><img src="images/exca1h.png" class="hov" alt="" /></div>
                            <h3>Excavation</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last">
                        <a href="service_detail.html">
                            <div class="img-blk"><img src="images/equip1.png" class="nor" alt="" /><img src="images/equip1h.png" class="hov" alt="" /></div>
                            <h3>Equipment</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is vague at best. But if you are asking how to add a repeating field to Options Framework, then this [tutorial](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/473/add-repeating-text-field-to-options-framework/) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find all you need to know.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/repeater/

One example

```
<?php if(get_field('repeater_field_name')): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while(has_sub_field('repeater_field_name')): ?>

        <li>sub_field_1 = <?php the_sub_field('sub_field_1'); ?>, sub_field_2 = <?php the_sub_field('sub_field_2'); ?>, etc</li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```